# Shopify products/delete webhook only returns ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

My ruby on rails app is supposed to do some things whenever a product is deleted. According to [Shopify's website here](https://shopify.dev/api/admin/rest/reference/events/webhook?api%5Bversion%5D=2021-04) the response to `products/delete` is supposed to be a JSON object with information such as the `product_id` associated with the product that was deleted:

```
{
  "id": 788032119674292922,
  "title": "Example T-Shirt",
  "body_html": null,
  "vendor": "Acme",
  "product_type": "Shirts",
  "created_at": null,
  "handle": "example-t-shirt",
  "updated_at": "2021-07-01T14:08:43-04:00",
  "published_at": "2021-07-01T14:08:43-04:00",
  "template_suffix": null,
  "published_scope": "web",
  "tags": "example, mens, t-shirt",
  "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/Product\/788032119674292922",
  "variants": [
    {
      "id": 642667041472713922,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "title": "",
      "price": "19.99",
      "sku": "example-shirt-s",
      "position": 0,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "24.99",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "inventory_management": "shopify",
      "option1": "Small",
      "option2": null,
      "option3": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "taxable": true,
      "barcode": null,
      "grams": 200,
      "image_id": null,
      "weight": 200.0,
      "weight_unit": "g",
      "inventory_item_id": null,
      "inventory_quantity": 75,
      "old_inventory_quantity": 75,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/642667041472713922"
    },
    {
      "id": 757650484644203962,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "title": "",
      "price": "19.99",
      "sku": "example-shirt-m",
      "position": 0,
      "inventory_policy": "deny",
      "compare_at_price": "24.99",
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "inventory_management": "shopify",
      "option1": "Medium",
      "option2": null,
      "option3": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "taxable": true,
      "barcode": null,
      "grams": 200,
      "image_id": null,
      "weight": 200.0,
      "weight_unit": "g",
      "inventory_item_id": null,
      "inventory_quantity": 50,
      "old_inventory_quantity": 50,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductVariant\/757650484644203962"
    }
  ],
  "options": [
    {
      "id": 527050010214937811,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "name": "Title",
      "position": 1,
      "values": [
        "Small",
        "Medium"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 539438707724640965,
      "product_id": 788032119674292922,
      "position": 0,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "alt": null,
      "width": 323,
      "height": 434,
      "src": "\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/shopifycloud\/shopify\/assets\/shopify_shirt-39bb555874ecaeed0a1170417d58bbcf792f7ceb56acfe758384f788710ba635.png",
      "variant_ids": [
      ],
      "admin_graphql_api_id": "gid:\/\/shopify\/ProductImage\/539438707724640965"
    }
  ],
  "image": null
}
```

However, whenever I go to test it by actually deleting a product in the Shopify Admin interface, I'm only getting the `id` in my response. Anybody know why this is happening? My setup for the other webhooks is the exact same and I'm not having any other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is an [open issue](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api/issues/830) on the shopify_api gem for version  `2021-01`. I don't think you are doing anything wrong. It looks like nobody has responded in a while to the issue, you might want to try to upgrade to [another version](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/versioning) to see if they fixed it in any of the newer versions.

EDIT: According to a [post](https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/customers-delete-webhook-only-returns-customer-id/td-p/298175) from 3/2017 the expected behaviour from deleted endpoints is to only return the ID of the resource that was deleted. This could be why the issue on Github is being ignored.

[image]

Comment: i'm using version 2021-04. I guess still an issue :(...I'll try a later API version

Comment: I was looking into it a bit further and in this post from 2017 https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/customers-delete-webhook-only-returns-customer-id/td-p/298175 one of Shopify's employees said that just returning an id is the expected behavior.